# Infinite Order Differential Equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, divergent-series

The functional equation
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} f(2x)+1$$
doesn't uniquely define a function. I could choose to define $f(1)$ however I want, and then propagate the value to all $f(2^m), m \in \mathbb{Z}$ in a way that satisfies the functional. However, I could choose to rewrite the functional equation as
$$ f(x)-1 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} e^{\ln(2)x D} f(x)  = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\left( 1 + \ln(2)xD +\ln(2)^2 \frac{ (xD)^2}{2!} + \ln(2)^3\frac{ (xD)^3}{3!}+\dots\right)f(x)$$
I am curious, with this formulation, is $f$ uniquely defined (perhaps, as the limit of solutions to differential equations up to order n, or maybe something else)? What initial conditions are needed to define the function fully (do we need all the derivatives at 0?)?

### Thoughts

One consideration is that $f(x)$ is formally equal to the (divergent) sum $\sum 2^{n^2} x^n$, so perhaps there is a unique way to regularize that series which provides a unique answer.

Mathematica can solve the first two differential equations. $f(x)-1 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}f(x)$ has
$$f(x) = \frac{-2}{-2 + \sqrt{2}x}$$
For $f(x)-1 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}(f(x)+ \ln(2) x f'(x))$ with the initial condition $f(0)=1$ we obtain
$$\log ^{-\frac{1}{\log (2)}}(2) e^{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x \log (2)}} x^{-\frac{1}{\log (2)}} \left(\sqrt{e} \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log (2)}} x^{\frac{1}{\log (2)}} \Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{\log (2)},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{x \log (2)}\right)+c_1 \sqrt[\log (2)]{\log (2)}\right) $$
The $e^{\frac{-1}{x}}$ term suggests the Taylor series expansion is probably not unique around $0$, since, at 0, $e^{\frac{-1}{x}}$ is invisible to a Taylor series.

Comment: +1 For the nice idea to use exponential operator for such a functional equation.

Comment: Did you not forget a $\ln(2)$ in your question ? We have the formula,  $$f(ax) = e^{ln(a)x\partial {x}}f(x)$$

Comment: @Zakhurf You're right; thank you for the catch

Comment: This is a functional differential equation similar to the delay-differential equation $g'(x)=cg(x+1)$. As the delay is forward, a solution via integration has to proceed backwards. For going forward, the initial history on $[1,2]$ has to be smooth with correct connections of values and derivatives at the boundary.